# Get 'processed' terminal output in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, terminal-emulator

I have some bytes that have escape sequences that move the cursor around, which causes the terminal to overwrite some text in the output. I want to "process" the bytes so that I only get the final output that appears when I print them out. For example:

```py
b = b'Using default tag: latest\r\nlatest: Pulling from library/hello-world\r\n\r\n\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Pulling fs layer \r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Downloading     423B/2.529kB\r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Download complete \r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Extracting  2.529kB/2.529kB\r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Extracting  2.529kB/2.529kB\r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Pull complete \r\x1b[1BDigest: sha256:31b9c7d48790f0d8c50ab433d9c3b7e17666d6993084c002c2ff1ca09b96391d\r\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest\r\ndocker.io/library/hello-world:latest\r\n'
s = b.decode("utf-8")
print(s)
```

The output of the above script is:

```
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world

Digest: sha256:31b9c7d48790f0d8c50ab433d9c3b7e17666d6993084c002c2ff1ca09b96391d
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
docker.io/library/hello-wo
```

I want to get the above output as a string inside python, as the string you see above, instead of with escape sequences and overwritten text. You can see the difference when you compare the lengths:

```py
b = b'Using default tag: latest\r\nlatest: Pulling from library/hello-world\r\n\r\n\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Pulling fs layer \r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Downloading     423B/2.529kB\r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Download complete \r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Extracting  2.529kB/2.529kB\r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Extracting  2.529kB/2.529kB\r\x1b[1B\x1b[1A\x1b[2K\r0e03bdcc26d7: Pull complete \r\x1b[1BDigest: sha256:31b9c7d48790f0d8c50ab433d9c3b7e17666d6993084c002c2ff1ca09b96391d\r\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest\r\ndocker.io/library/hello-world:latest\r\n'
s = b.decode("utf-8")

desired_output = """Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world

Digest: sha256:31b9c7d48790f0d8c50ab433d9c3b7e17666d6993084c002c2ff1ca09b96391d
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest
docker.io/library/hello-world:latest"""

print(len(s), len(desired_output))
```

Output:

```
544 238
```

One is almost two times longer than the other, even though `print(s)` and `print(desired_output)` result in the same text appearing in the terminal.

Initially I used a `pyte`, a terminal emulator library, where I could feed the bytes into a emulated terminal and "screengrab" the terminal for raw text afterwards. Unfortunately this method was really slow (up to 7s for 1 million bytes).

There must be a faster way, just because my actual terminal is able to process that many bytes in much less time.

I've been searching for a solution for a while now, so I would also really appreciate any leads or partial answers.

Comment: That seems difficult since the program doesn't handle the ANSI escape codes, the terminal does. You could potentially just write your own function to move a virtual cursor around and analyze it, but I'm not sure if there is a better solution.